# Android RecyclerView Adapter Update and SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I currently use a SwipeRefreshLayout with a RecyclerView for displaying a few images. So if a user wipe down, the SwipeRefreshLayout will display the waiting animation and the app starts to download and generate the images in async tasks. After this, I have this piece of code:

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ImageRecyclerViewAdapter(bitmaps));
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

But the animation is only enabled as long as the app downloads and generate the images. If they are sent to the recyclerview with the adapter, the animation stops so it hides itself one or two seconds before the images are shown.

Where is the fault?

Comment: Why not just use a Handler with PostDelayed, to delay the hiding of the refresh indicator by like two seconds, this gives the recyclerview some time to load the images?

Comment: i think that the delay due to setting bitmaps with adapter , or may be you settings bitmaps with other thread

Comment: The handler may work but the goal is to create a connection between image loading and refresh indicator.